# How to install Windows alongside preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

this is my first time on askubuntu.com, which is just great :)

I have to install Windows 8.1 or 10 on my new Dell Inspirion 3543 laptop, which came with preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04  UEFI. I've read many topics with similar problem but nothing is exactly like mine so I would like to know everything:
I have next partitions right now:
1) ESP (524 MB/ 502 MB free) 
2) DIAGS(42 MB)
3) OS(3.2GB)
4) Filesystem(488GB) ext4
5) Swap(8.4GB)
6) Free Space(1.1MB)

Should I resize this large 488GB partition and make space for Windows and than start installation on that partition?
What will happend with ESP, will Windows create another or maybe delete it?
Will this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu). *Step One – Make space for Windows* (from the accepted answer).

Comment: Note that it sounds like your computer is booting in EFI mode, so pay particular attention to the EFI-related comments in the duplicate question. (Some details that are not flagged for BIOS vs. EFI boot mode actually apply only to BIOS-mode installs.)

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

You can control partitions on Windows Installer, but later you need to restore the GRUB using a live cd.

So create a NTFS partition and install Windows on it.